# Energy of black body radiation

Tags: radiation

Does radiated energy of black body radiation due to the transition of electrons to higher energy state? or due to the increasing vibration of atoms themselves?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is the black body radiation so important?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/107907/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the various physical mechanisms for energy transfer to the photon during blackbody emission?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/59213/)